# How to use RegexKitLite correctly

Tags: iphone, regex, ios4

I am using RegexKitLite, i want to validate that my uitextfield has + prefixed and contains numeric length of 13 or only 13 numeric values.

Please let me know

Below is the code i tried

```
textview.text = @"123458kdkmfmdfmsdf"

NSString *regEx = @"{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"; 
NSString *match = [textView.text stringByMatching:regEx]; 
if ([match isEqual:@""] == NO)
 { NSLog(@"Phone number is %@", match); }
else { NSLog(@"Not found."); }
```

the ouput i want is belo
ouput 1 = "1234567891012"
or output 2 can be like "+1234567891012

Comment: Do you want to add only 13 numeric values or any ? give me your output which you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
NSString * forAlphaNumeric = @"^([+]{1})(a-zA-Z0-9{13})$";
BOOL isMatch = [yourString isMatchedByRegex:forAlphaNumeric];

NSString * forNumeric = @"^([+]{1})(0-9{13})$";
BOOL isMatch = [yourString isMatchedByRegex:forNumeric];
```